# CSS grid like fibonacci

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid, fibonacci

this is the desired result (similar to fibonacci's grid):

[image]

I know this is posible using css grid, but as i'm not as familiar as I would like to, I tried using this https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/ like so:

[image]

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
    .div1 {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
    }
    .div2 {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
    }
    .div3 {
        grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    }
    .div4 {
        grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
    }
}
```

I had to adapt it to my markup and it looks like this (run the code snippet)

```css
.post__gallery--4 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  grid-row-gap: 26px;
}

.post__gallery--4 .post__image:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

.post__gallery--4 .post__image:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
}

.post__gallery--4 .post__image:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.post__gallery--4 .post__image:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="post__gallery post__gallery--4">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1145/763/abstract/" class="post__image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/552/830/abstract/" class="post__image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/552/402/abstract/" class="post__image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/552/401/abstract/" class="post__image">
</div>
```

but for some reason, the last image is outside the grid and it pushes the content below.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Images as grid or flex items often exhibit quirky behavior in at least one major browser. Consider wrapping the images in divs, making them the grid items. Then set the images to `width: 100%; height: auto`, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using grid areas but if you want repeating pattern then you should create multiple elements with the same area layout.

```css
.area {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
            "one one"
            "two three"
            "two four";
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.area > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
   grid-area: one;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: two;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  grid-area: three;
}

img:nth-child(4) {
  grid-area: four;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="area">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1145x763" class="post__image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x830" class="post__image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x402" class="post__image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x401" class="post__image">
  </div>
  
  <div class="area">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1145x763" class="post__image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x830" class="post__image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x402" class="post__image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x401" class="post__image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way with one wrapper element is using grid-auto columns and rows. To select every nth-element for each of 4 elements for example every second in 4 elements you can use `:nth-child(4n + 2)`

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.gallery>img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

img:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 1;
}

img:nth-child(4n + 3),
img:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  grid-row: span 1;
  grid-column: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1145x763" class="post__image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x830" class="post__image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x402" class="post__image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x401" class="post__image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1145x763" class="post__image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x830" class="post__image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x402" class="post__image">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/552x401" class="post__image">
</div>
```